# Urgent help: system doesnt boot after selecting xorg drivers in additional drivers

Tags: drivers, nvidia

I wanted to start ubuntu MATE 15.10 without nvidia drivers which were detected as 353. something. I selected xorg drivers and rebooted. Now I get some drm:intel_pipeline error and I can only use tty.

How can I select nvidia drivers from tty?

Thanks

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Just run

```
sudo apt-get install nvidia-353
```

Then reboot, Nvidia driver will be back.